# Excel query within PowerShell

Tags: performance, excel, powershell, sharepoint

I am currently using the following query to add a specific row (with 10 columns) from an Excel spreadsheet (~1500 rows and hosted on SharePoint - I've also tested locally with the same issue) to an array in PowerShell.

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

$connectstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$Source;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'"; $connection.ConnectionString = $connectstring

$connection.open()

$cmdObject = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand

$query = "Select * from [Sheet1$] 
WHERE [Sheet1$].[Test] = '$Test'"
$cmdObject.CommandText = $query
$cmdObject.CommandType = "Text"
$cmdObject.Connection = $connection

$oReader = $cmdObject.ExecuteReader()

[void]$oReader.Read()
    $Global:oData = New-Object PSObject
    $oData | Add-Member NoteProperty List1    $oReader[0]
    ...
    $oData | Add-Member NoteProperty List10   $oReader[9]

$oReader.Close()
$cmdObject.Dispose()
$connection.Close()
$connection.Dispose()
```

This works absolutely fine, however, it is often quite slow. Is there any way in which I could speed up the query? I can't add the entire Excel sheet into an array, as the data changes throughout the day and is queried regularly.

I've found other questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314858/speed-up-reading-an-excel-file-in-powershell). However, that doesn't seem relevant to this particular issue.

Comment: The dots is supposed to be understood as you truncating 8 lines from you code? Don't do things like that when you need a review. Code you remove makes means you are not including the complete solution and can obfuscate improvements we could make to it. Also I don't see how this code adds data to a spreadsheet